# anchor tag not clickable text overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in the below fiddle i have anchor tag with href and background image in this structure , the text is stopping the href to clickable any idea how to solve the issue , with the same HTML structure ?

```
<div class="banner-container">
<div class="banner-box">
    <div class="banner-div">
        <div class="bannerheading">
            <p><span>The correct link should be&nbsp;</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <div class="banner-img" style="background-image:url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png');">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

please check the red border inside the box is not clickable https://jsfiddle.net/uqbhcdn6/1/.

any idea will be appreciated :)

Comment: Which one should be clickable `.banner-div` or `.banner-box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pointer-events:none;` property to the `.banner-div` class.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to give the `.bannerheading` the style `pointer-events: none;`, though this will make it impossible to select the text in `.bannerheading`:

```css
.banner-container {
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.banner-container .banner-box {
    border-radius: 12px;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-color: #1C2841;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.banner-container .banner-box .banner-div {
    top: 50%;
    height: auto;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.banner-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 34%;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.banner-container .banner-box .banner-div .bannerheading {
    color: #fff;
}

banner-container .banner-box .banner-img {
    min-height: 350px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.banner-img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container">
    <div class="banner-box">
        <div class="banner-div">
            <div class="bannerheading">
                <p><span>The correct link should be&nbsp;</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <div class="banner-img" style="background-image:url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png');">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways

1.You can add `z-index` and `position:relative` for z-index to get applied.

2.You can add `pointer-events:none`